# Deserializing Jarray in JSON.NET

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization

i need to deserialize this.

```
{"previous_cursor_str":"0","next_cursor":0,"ids":[741999686,240455509,126524150,143548100,124328422,624776268,393738125,587829914,280834485,64818350,282713007,90425850,759794,164401208,114771958,114364910,89725893],"previous_cursor":0,"next_cursor_str":"0"}
```

any idea?

Comment: It should be just `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 5):

Its a JObject really with an array of Id's inside it.

First you can create a class to represent the json like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string previous_cursor_str { get; set; }
    public int next_cursor { get; set; }
    public List<int> ids { get; set; }
    public int previous_cursor { get; set; }
    public string next_cursor_str { get; set; }
}
```

Then to deserialize the json into the object you do this:

```
var myJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

Or if you just want the ids in a array:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);

var idArray = obj["ids"].Children().Select(s=>s.value<string>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried https://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/ and got the code below. Which is qhite the same as geepie's class. nice tool.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Example
{
  class Result
  {
    [JsonProperty("previous_cursor_str")]
    public string PreviousCursorStr { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("next_cursor")]
    public int NextCursor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ids")]
    public IList<int> Ids { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("previous_cursor")]
    public int PreviousCursor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("next_cursor_str")]
    public string NextCursorStr { get; set; }
  }    

  public static unsafe void Main()
  {
    Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result> (" ... your string ...");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
}
```